# LabVIEW robotics with Pioneer P3DX

Tags: robotics, labview

Is there support for MobileRobots Pioneer 3-DX (P3DX) Differential Drive Robot in LabVIEW ? 
http://www.ni.com/white-paper/9079/en#toc4

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like there might be something for you in here : [NI_LabView_Interface on mobilerobots.com](http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/NI_LabView_Interface) There's a link that points to [NI LabVIEW MobileRobots Interface](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-5584)

Comment: as in the article, i also got the same error:   Client Demo.vi with the MobileSim, and I've gotten the same log info:

ArClientBase: Connection to  closed

ArClientBase: Lost connection to server (couldn't recv).